# How admin can update user meta using gravity form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, usermetadata

I have gravity form user registration, in which a user can update their own metadata but I want that an admin can also update any user data just by adding their email address on some specific field.  if there is any plugin or code which can fulfill my need please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a security risk to me. Why not edit the user data through the backend?

Comment: Actually my client is not so technical , i am trying to give him  the easiest method possible.